# Automate Creation of Route53 records with external-dns

Tags: documentation, document, aws-route53

Must contain the following:
Ensure that it is configurable via Ingress annotations; only annotated ingresses should be setup automatically (use appropriate Route 53 hosted zone - 312centos.com, 312ubuntu.com, 312redhat.com)

Deliverables:
Working automatic record creation within Route 53 via Ingress annotations

README explaining external-dns architecture/background as well as installation/configuration

use github visual studio code etc.